# Facing issue while creating .CSV using File Helper library with c#

Tags: c#, export, export-to-csv, filehelpers

I am creating .csv using file helper library (https://www.filehelpers.net/docs/html/R_Project_FileHelpers.htm) I am facing two issues as follows:

1) I am passing string to export which contain special characters like "advantage's, -" these character get replace with some garbage value like â€”. I dont know why this is happening? and how I can deal with it?

For Above issue I tried with http://www.becsv.com/csv-viewer.php site when I am using this to see my data it showing correct data. even I open my CSV file in notpad it also contain correct data only problem with excel.

2) I am passing filename which is of 50 Characters long and same name is appearing as sheet name, but sheetname can accept only 13 characters. So is there any way to pass filename and sheet name different?

If any one knows about these issues please help me.

Comment: #1 sounds like an encoding issue. You've probably got a file being saved in ASCII, but your source data is unicode, or something along those lines.

Comment: What do you mean by `sheet`? There are no sheets in a csv file.

Comment: For sheet name assuming you mean in Excel?  You can not assign a sheet name in a .csv file, it only opens in Excel because you probably have that set as default app to open .csv files.

Comment: @vbnet3d, while it is a text encoding issue, the problem is not because the file was saved in ASCII, as you assume. If the file were saved in ASCII mode (using .NET TextWriter capabilities), artifacts such as â€ would not be observed (a UTF-8 character would not be converted into two ASCII characters/bytes, so to speak). It is the viewing/reading of UTF-8 in ASCII mode that misinterprets UTF-8 code sequences and displays artifacts such as â€. So, the solution would be to either read the produced CSV in UTF-8 mode, or save the CSV in ASCII mode (with the conversion limits this would entail)

Comment: FYI: `â€”` is the UTF-8 code sequence for the "em dash" (U+2014), visible when trying to incorrectly display UTF-8 text in some "ANSI/ASCII mode" (air quotes!) using an encoding such as Windows-1252...

Comment: Is there any other way, other than encoding?